# Why is first gets() input is lost in this c program?

Tags: c, gets

In the following simple code the input of the first gets is not showing up.
Any help please?

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    char tmp[1];
    char anystr[10], srchstr[1];

    printf("Enter an string : ");
    gets(anystr);

    printf("Enter any character you want to search in input string: ");
    gets(srchstr);

    printf("anystr : %s\n",anystr);
    printf("anystr : %c\n",anystr[0]);
    printf("srchstr : %c\n",srchstr[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

The Output is null for first fgets string anystr:

```
Enter an string : hello
Enter any character you want to search in input string: h
anystr : 
anystr : 
srchstr : h
```

Comment: WTF are you using `gets` - It is bad news, deprecated ....

Comment: `char srchstr[1]` is not large enough to hold the one character you are entering *plus* the NUL terminator.

Comment: an array of size 1 is a single `char` -- how would you ever expect this to hold any "string" (except the empty string of course)?

Comment: Title says "second" is lost. Question says "first" is lost. Which is it?

Comment: It's a perfect demonstration **why** `gets()` doesn't exist any more. obviously, `srchstr` is placed in memory directly before `anystr`, so the second `gets()` overwrites the first character of `anystr` with a `0` -- intending to terminate `srchstr`, but instead making `anystr` the empty string. At least no nasal demons for you (yet, unless you enter even longer lines). **don't ever use `gets()`**.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I was already editing when your comment appeared and I did not notice, so I did not actually take your know how. Hope you do not mind anyway.

Comment: See [Why is `gets()` so dangerous that it should never, ever be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036).

Comment: @Yunnosch and I was already about to UV your answer, but am busy looking for a good pair of duplicates to close this mess :D Jonathan just added the link to the one I already found, still missing a good canonic one on string terminators :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Why not make this one the canonic? It is a very nice tiny example, practically tailor-made to fit the purpose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem because you have undefined behaviour.
The UB is caused by having second `gets()` write beyond the 1-char array `srchstr`. What is written beyond is the terminator `'\0'`.
See the `gets()` docu: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets

No answer to this question should omit to mention (using Jonathan Lefflers nice link):
[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

That is it. UB and dangerous. Done. End of answer.

Well....
One speculation of which specific nasal demon is flying around would be:
`strchr` is located right before `anystr`. This means that the one beyond access hits right the first char inside `anystr`.
I.e. it terminates that other string right after zero characters.
I.e. it makes it empty.
Printing it therefor has no output, even though the second character is still from the perviously written string.

Comment: Thanks yunnosch. Increasing the length of srchstr solved the problem.

Comment: @MRZ,  Don't use `gets()` at all.  Instead, use `fgets()` (remembering, of course, that the input buffer will contain the trailing '\n' which will need to be removed, probably by a call to `strspn()`

Comment: @user3629249 Did you notice the link by Jonathan Leffler which explains in detail what probably is the background of your comment? I fail to see your point because of the existence of that link inside my answer. Or did you execlusively address MRZ and just wanted to stress the link? In that case I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `gets()` as pointed here in `man 3 fges`

> Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing
>   the
>          data in advance how many  characters  gets()  will  read,  and  because
>          gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it
>          is extremely dangerous to use.  It has  been  used  to  break  computer
>          security.  Use fgets() instead.

Use `fgets()` like

```
fgets(anystr,sizeof(anystr),stdin);
```

Also `char srchstr[1];` should be `char srchstr;` as you are asking in `printf` *Enter any character you want to search in input string:*

And to scan `srchstr` use `scanf(" %c",&srchstr);`

you may want something like

```
int main(void ) {
        char anystr[10],srchstr;
        printf("Enter an string : ");
        fgets(anystr,sizeof(anystr),stdin);/*use fgets instead of gets */

        printf("Enter any character you want to search in input string: ");
        scanf(" %c",&srchstr);/* give the space before %c to avoid buffering problem */

        printf("anystr : %s\n",anystr);
        printf("anystr : %c\n",anystr[0]);
        printf("srchstr : %c\n",srchstr);

        return 0;
}
```